# Get User Information from ZODB

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

I am trying to get information out of my Plone site regarding Users. It is relatively easy to get info out of the portal_catalog. However, user info isn't in the portal_catalog.

Can somebody tell me how to get user info out of the ZODB from my Plone site? Basically, I am looking to get back a list of user ids.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also the portal_membership tool.  For example, you could do:

```
utool=context.portal_url
portal=utool.getPortalObject()
mtool=portal.portal_membership
members=mtool.getRoster()
```

Answer (score 0):

, I've been fooling around with acl_users folder and found that I can do this:

```
users_tool = getToolByName(app_obj,'acl_users')
```

And a dir() quicky revealed all the methods I need to extract the data! :) –